# Upvote this вопрос

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, голосование

Отсутствует перевод во всплывающих подсказках на кнопках голосования, количестве голосов на вопросе/ответе, кнопки временной шкалы вопроса/ответа

[image: Upvote this вопрос]
[image: Downvote]

[image: Totals]
[image: upvotes&downvotes]

[image: Activity]

---

UPD. также не переведены всплывающие подсказки на нажатых кнопках "за" и "против"

[image: Useful]
[image: Not useful]

Comment: *Тот момент, когда заголовок звучит как призыв к действию )*

Comment: _This вопрос has received 11 upvotes and 0 downvotes._ ;)

Comment: Эх.. какие ж неудобные и бесполезные подсказки... Как бы их отключить?

Comment: @Qwertiy почему бесполезные? Если человек первый раз на сайте и никогда не был на подобных форумах, для него это будет полезно. И по моему, 3-4 месяца назад у них был нормальный перевод.

Comment: @Стас, и тултипы были нормальные браузерные. Если пользователь новый, то да. А если я в топ 10 сайта, то, вероятно, нет. Слишком много контента закрывают. К ним надо приделать кнопку "больше не показывать".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Переводы добавил, ссылки не привожу, можете сами глянуть на https://ru.traducir.win/, благо доступ есть у всех.

Если что-то не так с переводом - предлагайте свои правки и оставляйте комментарий под этим ответом, удачные решения утвердим.

Переводы, вероятно, появятся с ближайшей новой сборкой сайта. Текущая rev 2020.6.18.37100

Answer (score 2):

Эти подсказки можно скрыть таким css:

```
.js-voting-container :not(.js-bounty-award) + .s-popover {
  display: none;
}
```